# Problema para ajustar largura de colunas no Latex

Tags: latex

Estou criando a seguinte tabela em LATEX, mas não consigo de forma alguma encontrar uma largura que seja interessante para as 5 colunas da minha tabela.
O código da tabela está abaixo, ressalto que a tabela terá muitas outras linhas, mas ainda não inseri, pois estava tentando arrumar as colunas.

Existe algum comando que ajusta da melhor forma possível a largura de forma automática?

CÓDIGO:

```
    \begin{table}[!h]
\adjusted
\caption{Studies developed using ML algorithms to predict and classify sensory responses based on non-sensory data.}
\label{ml_algorithms}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1.2cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5}|}
        \\
        \toprule
        \column{\textbf{Product}} & \column{\textbf{Objective}} & \column{\textbf{Sensory test}} & \column{\textbf{Algorithm}} & \column{\textbf{Reference}}\\ 
        \endtoprule
        \cmidrule(l){1-5}
        Coffee & 
        Investigating the feasibility of training machine learning (ML) and deep learning (DL) models to predict specialty coffee flavors using NIR of ground coffee as input. &
        Trained panelists  Determination of flavor descriptions and categories by Q Arabica Graders &
        Support vector machine (SVM), DL and deep convolutional neural network (DCNN) & 
        Chang et al. (2021).
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Como resultado do código acima, obtenho a seguinte saída:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]